# Crouton: use Builder to set custom font and textSize

Tags: android, crouton

Crouton library has `Builder` class that has some methods such as `setTextSize()`, `setFontName()` and etc. How can I use this class to change default this library configuration?

For example:

```
Crouton.makeText(activity, "HELLO" , Style.ALERT, rootLayout).show();
```

How can I use a builder for this line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as I could understand your question, you want something like this:

```
import de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget.crouton.Style.Builder;

Crouton.makeText(activity, "HELLO" , new Style.Builder()
                                                .setTextSize(12)
                                                .setFontName(someFontName)
                                                ...
                                                .build(),
                                     rootLayout)
                                     .show();
```